# I am getting segmentation fault. I have made the code to see if the brackets are balanced or not. C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, stack

I have written this code to check for balanced brackets in an expression. I have used linked list implementation of stacks. I am getting a segmentation error. Please explain why do we get segmentation error in the first place, I am newbie and having a hard time understanding the concept of segmentation errors and memory management in general.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct stack {
    char data;
    struct stack *next;
};
struct stack *top = NULL;
void push(char data) {
    struct stack *temp = (struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = top;
    top = temp;
    return;
}
void pop() {
    struct stack *temp = top;
    top = top->next;
    return;
}
int isEmpty() {
    if (top == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    char array[250];
    cout << "Enter code and end with $ sign : " << endl;
    cin.getline(array, 250, '$');
    while (array[i] != '\n') {
        if (array[i] == '{' || array[i] == '[' || array[i] == '(') {
            push(array[i]);
        } else if (array[i] == '}' || array[i] == ']' || array[i] == ')') {
            if (array[i] == '}' && top->data == '{')
                pop();
            else if (array[i] == ']' && top->data == '[')
                pop();
            else if (array[i] == ')' && top->data == '(')
                pop();
            else {
                cout << "Not Balanced" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (isEmpty() == 1)
        cout << "Balanced" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Not Balanced" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please apply indentation, using spaces, to your code.  This will make it more readable.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: In C++ prefer `nullptr` to C's `NULL`. Avoid `using namespace std` as the `std::` prefix serves to separate Standard Library code from your code.

Comment: Prefer to use `operator new` instead of `malloc`.  The `malloc` function does not call constructors.

Comment: Also, use that newer, more recent, data type called `bool` instead of `int`.  Using one or zero is such an ancient technique (like days of FORTRAN and COBOL).

Comment: You don't need to use `struct` when declaring pointers or instances.  This is primarily allowed for porting C programs to C++ (and maybe ancient C++ programs).

Comment: It's also time to learn about `std::string` as this will save you from the unending misery and suffering that C strings are.

Comment: Please indicate for which input you get a segmentation fault

Comment: You need to check that the stack isn't empty before you try to access its top element. (You have problems with any input that ends with too many closing brackets.)

Answer (score 1):

So I will begin by explaining what a segmentation fault means and why it happens. A segmentation fault happens when a program tries to read memory that it's not allowed to read. This can happen if you try to get an array element that is outside of the allocated array and it can also happen if you dereference a null pointer.

I think the problem in your case might be that your loop fails to end in the right place and ends up accessing array elements outside of the 250 spaces allocated. according to this reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/, getline() doesn't actually include the newline character into the array, however it always appends a null character '\0'.

Try changing `while(array[i]!='\n')` to `while(array[i]!='\0')` and let me know if that fixes it. If not I will keep looking for more errors. Your code is not super readable and there are a lot of places that something could go wrong. I would recommend adding empty lines between each of your functions.

Also, as molbdnilo mentioned, you will also get a segmentation fault if you have too many closing braces, since in this case top will be equal to null and your program will try to dereference top using `top->data` in your condition

Also I notice you're using a lot of C conventions such as struct, malloc(), and NULL. It works fine, but make sure to recognize that there is a difference between C and C++ and try to stick to C++ sources when learning so you don't get confused. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help, the code works fine now. I just shifted from C to C++, will try to use C++ more and also keep my code more readable.

Comment: All of my cases are working except when I first use } or ] or )

Comment: Are you still having this issue? do you get a seg fault when you first use closing braces? I didn't look too hard but I'm assuming that top starts out as null so if you try to look at top->data before adding anything to top, you probably get a segfault. A way to fix this would be to add a check right before top->data == [whatever opening brace] for top == NULL. most programming languages, including c and c++ will stop evaluating once a condition is sure to be true so you won't get a segfault if you check for null first in the if statement.

Comment: Also what I would recommend doing is have the method pop() return top->data instead of checking the global top. idk if you know about return types, but you can have pop return the character on top of the queue and you can check if top == NULL and deal with it inside of pop()